# Data jumbled when setting Zimbabwe CRS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, proximity

I have got point data in Zimbabwe and am having a lot of trouble getting the projection right.

I have tried saving the QGIS project and layers to to WGS 84/UTM zone 36 and this now displays correctly in qgis.

However I need to calculate distance to the nearest road from each point (originally raster data). I tried NNjoin in qgis but it always aborts.

So I upload the data to arcmap instead to use the near tool, however it displays in degrees not km.

Comment: It looks like you have a coordinate system problem, see if any of the suggestions at https://ihatecoordinatesystems.com/ help.

Comment: You don't "set" data to a projection/coordinate system unless it either is already in that CRS but is missing the CRS definition or has had the CRS incorrectly defined. You need to re-set the CRS back to the correct projection (possibly EPSG:4209?) and then project/export the data to the new CRS so the coordinates change.  Setting the CRS to a different (incorrect) projection is like changing the file extension of a Word document from .docx to .pdf and expecting it to open correctly in a PDF reader.  It won't, because it's still a Word document, you need to actually convert your doc to pdf.,

Comment: Thanks for your help @user2856. I saved the layer to the new CRS and then the buffer tool was in km in QGIS. However when I use the newly saved layer in Arcmap it is in decimal! I need arcmap to do a near analysis on the data in km.

Comment: Please post your data and a Lat/Long near the center of where it's supposed to be.

Comment: This is a chunk of the data as its a large dataset and the coordinates are -16.9,29.5 (the data covers northern Zimbabwe) https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bLq5Yd9pd1pCZoyCVptzQk6dICuIzz17?usp=sharing

Comment: Those points seem to be in UTM correctly now.  Each point is about 26.7 m from its neighbour.  If you're having trouble with those points in ArcGIS, either edit your question  (inc. re-tagging to ArcMap) to ask about the near analysis issue or ask a new question and detail the steps and the output.  However, the data just appear to be a grid of points.  Are they the centroids of pixels of a raster dataset?  If so, you might be better doing your analysis in raster as it is more efficient for distance calcs on a grid.

Comment: Thanks for loking into this. They are centroids. I tried initially to do distance from raster pixels but couldn't find a command/get it to work so was told to convert to point which took me hours. I have just updated the question.

Comment: This is much more easily done using raster. In QGIS it's a bit fiddly as you have to convert the lines to raster and merge them with the other raster, but in ArcGIS you can just use the Euclidean distance tool,.